# How to pass data from EJB Interceptor to Interceptor in Async EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb

I have 2 Stateless EJBs StatelessA and StatelessB, both of them have interceptors InterceptorA and InterceptorB respectively. Also, StatelessB has Asynchronous methods. Something like this:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(InterceptorA.class)
public class StatelessA{...

@Stateless
@Asynchronous
@Interceptors(InterceptorB.class)
public class StatelessB{...
```

When calling a method on StatelessA, it calls several StatelessB methods and returns a value.
I am trying to develop 2 interceptors to store the total time and the subtotal times of StatelessB calls, this is the objective of the interceptors.

I need to do it so InterceptorA can see the detail of InterceptorB data, so I store only a value in the DB, containing the total time (of SLSB A) and the subtotal times (of SLSB B).

I tried using a ThreadLocal variable (containing a list of times, something like long[]), which works fine if StatelessB is not asyncrhonous.
The problem is that when it is asynchronous, the variable is not available, since it is running in a different thread (AFAIK).

I also tried injecting EJBContext or using the InvocationContext, but none of them works.

Can someone point me out what other alternatives do I have?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my question with what I ended up doing.
The only way I found to pass a variable from interceptor A to interceptor B was adding a parameter to the EJBs A and B, something like this:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(InterceptorA.class)
public class StatelessA{
public void methodA(Object reserved, ...other params )

@Stateless
@Asynchronous
@Interceptors(InterceptorB.class)
public class StatelessB{
public void methodB(Object reserved, ...other params)
```

This way, when InterceptorA is called, I'll set the reserved parameter with the data I need to share with InterceptorB. 
InterceptorB will access this variable with no issue getting it from the parameters.

The down side to this solution is that the dummy parameters are needed, coupling in some way the EJBs with the interceptors..

Comment: For wildfly check this [is-there-clean-way-to-pass-context-data-to-asynchronous-ejb-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430969/is-there-clean-way-to-pass-context-data-to-asynchronous-ejb-call)

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking this over and over, and arrived to a solution, which is using the security context to pass data.
The solution involves using the only data propagated in an asynchronous invocation, as specified in EJB 3.1:

> **4.5.4 Security** Caller security principal propagates with an asynchronous method invocation. Caller security principal propagation
>   behaves exactly the same for asynchronous method invocations as it
>   does for synchronous session bean invocations.

In JBoss, one can access the security context and use a data map in it to pass the values from InterceptorA to InterceptorB, as follows:

In InterceptorA:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextAssociation.getSecurityContext();
securityContext.getData().put("interceptorAData",data);
```

In InterceptorB:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextAssociation.getSecurityContext();
securityContext.getData().get("interceptorAData");
```

I tested it and it works great in JBoss EAP 6.1.

This solution implies couplig the interceptor to the server implementation (JBoss AS), but the principle works for other servers.
The advantage is that it decouples the application logic from the interceptors, which was the first objective.
I appreciate any comments.

Comment: I tried this and it worked for my peculiar situation at least until there's any pitfall whatsoever... However, none that I know about has surfaced yet... so I may as well give a +1

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to store the information you need in an @Entity object and then use the @PersistenceContext annotation to inject an EntityManager into the beans to persist and find the data? Something like:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
...
method() {
MyEntityTimer met = new MyEntityTimer(getCurrentTime(), id);
entityManager.persist(met);
}
...
elsewhere:
MyEntityTimer met = entityManager.find(MyEntityTimer.class, id);
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE")
public class MyEntityTimer {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) That could work, but how would I pass the "id" value from the interceptorA to InterceptorB? I don't want to add any new parameters to the methods in the Beans..

Comment: Could you create a new class level variable and add a new method that passes the id from A to B? Perhaps before you call the first method in B, call B.setId(id).

Comment: It's not possible to pass the id from A to B without modifying the EJBs. I found a way adding a parameter to the EJBs, reserving a variable for the interceptors. I'll answer the question with this detail. Thanks anyway!