# Is there clean way to pass context data to @Asynchronous ejb call?

Tags: java, asynchronous, wildfly

In wildfly I execute stateless ejb method asynchronously (it is mapped with @Asynchronous annotation). In the calling method I have some context information in thread local. What is the best way to pass this data to async method? I don't want to add additional parameter to async method signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of ugly plumbing it can be resolved as follows (wildfly 8.x.x):

```
if (SecurityContextAssociation.getSecurityContext()==null)
    SecurityContextAssociation.setSecurityContext(new JBossSecurityContext("background-job"));
SecurityContext current = SecurityContextAssociation.getSecurityContext();
final Object cred = current.getUtil().getCredential();
final Subject s = current.getUtil().getSubject();
final Principal up = current.getUtil().getUserPrincipal();
boolean needToUpdatePrincipal=true;
if (up instanceof TenantPrincipal) {
    if (t.getTenantName().equals(((TenantPrincipal) up).getAdditonalField())) {
        needToUpdatePrincipal=false;
    }
}
if (needToUpdatePrincipal) {
    TenantPrincipal tp=new TenantPrincipal(up.getName());
    tp.setAdditionalField(t.getTenantName());
    current.getUtil().createSubjectInfo(
            , cred, (Subject) s);
}
```

Basically you need to create your own Principal class and set context data in the additional field of its instance.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you have only 2 options:

1. Passing value as a parameter
2. Storing that value in some global place. Like static variable.

The first option is much cleaner and easier. Don't use the second one :)

Comment: The problem with first option is that I have not one but tens of asynchronous methods and I don't want to do such extensive refactoring. And parameter than I need to pass isn't usually used directly in those methods, but deeper in call hierarchy. So it would be better to access it in another way from the place I really need. The static variable alone isn't thread safe.

Comment: Thread-safety depends on how you use that variable. You can have `AtomicReference`, you can access it in `synchronized` block only, you can have thread-safe container for your data in static variable. Options are plenty.

Comment: All I need is to make sure that when accessing it this is exactly same value as in the calling method (like it was request scoped). I could use for example ThreadLocal but still the problem is, how to propagate the data?

Comment: Don't konw the current state but @AsynchronousScoped was discussed to be included in Java EE 8.